# bugs in mobile version

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

There are quite few annoying bugs in the mobile/tablet version of the site.

One of the most annoying ones is when I want to upvote a comment the comments is transferred downwards and not upvoted. The same happens when I touch the comment.

Another bug is the inconsistency in the way comments are displayed, the font size varies from one comment to another.

When typing there are random jumps.

I think the mobile/tablet versions need to be more thoroughly tested. Right now the experience is not pleasant at all.

Comment: I am using Chrome on Nexus 7.

Comment: Mobile Chrome isn't currently a browser we support (but given that Google is killing the standard Android browser, despite those known Chrome bugs you describe, we're aware that we'll have to change that at some point).

Comment: the site works very well with most main browsers. speaking as web developer, its more that the mobile browsers are relatively new & still have quirks/bugs that havent been ironed out...(ie not too fair to single out this site, they dont work exactly on many other sites too). the prob is esp acute with sites like this which have a lot of dynamic (js) code.